# Help with LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I currently a list of a Supplier class, within that supplier class is a list of orders.

Each order has a userID and an empty string variable for username.

I then have a list of users which contains userID and username.

The way I am doing this now is:

```
foreach(supplier s in SupplierList)
{
    foreach (order o in s.childorders)
    {
        user u = _users.First(p => p.userid == o.userid);
        o.username = u.username;
    }
}
```

I feel this might be a little inefficient and I was wondering if it is possible to compact it down into one linq query?

The logic should be

set supplierslist.childorders.username to the value in _users where `supplierslist.childorders.userid == _users.userid`.

Im fairly new to Linq so any advice for this would be apreciated, or also if its a bad idea and to leave it as it is / reasons why would be good too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var orderUserPairs = SupplierList
    .SelectMany(s => s.ChildOrders)
    .Join(_users, o => o.UserId, u => u.userId, (Order, User) => new {Order, User});

foreach (var orderUserPair in orderUserPairs)
    orderUserPair.Order.username = orderUserPair.User.username;
```

Though having both `username` and `userId` as part of order looks suspicious.

Comment: Order actually doesnt contain Username, in this case the 'real' order class just contains the userID, I am using MVVM and have a class in between Order and my UI which supports propertychanged and this contains UserName as username is only displayed on the UI.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do here is iterate over a collection (many collections, really, but it doesn't make a difference) and *mutate* its members. LINQ is not really targeted at performing mutating operations but rather at querying. You can do it with LINQ, but it's [against the spirit of the tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

If you are constructing the `SupplierList` yourself, it might be possible to fetch the data appropriately with LINQ so that it comes pre-populated as you want it to be.

Otherwise, I 'd leave the `foreach` as it is. You can make a dictionary that maps ids to users to make the inner loop faster, but that's your call and it depends on your data size.

Answer (score 1):

If users list contains many elements, it can be really slow so I'd use a temporary dictionary:

```
var userById = users.GroupBy(x => x.userid)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First()); 

foreach(var order in supplier.SelectMany(x => x.childorders))
{
   order.username = userById[order.userid].username;
}
```

Comment: It was full of typos, fixed (I hope) :S

Comment: I think `Join` groups it better than `Dictionary` since `Join` has more info on which items will be joined.

Comment: @SnowBear: I've just translated the code he posted, improving users names retrieving through dictionary lookup. I don't see any clear advantage in using Join here...

Comment: @dig, You're saying `dictionary will be faster`, I'm saying that `Join` **should** be even more faster.

Comment: @SnowBear: Correction. Yes, maybe Join could be faster but just if users are more than orders. That's because Join probably uses 2 lookups instead of one (like in my method). BTW the difference is really small... and when users are less my method is faster (tested).

Comment: @SnowBear: BTW is totally ~1 sec on 1M users x 10K suppliers and viceversa... ;)

Comment: @dig, Ok, you convinced me :) The point why I thought `Join` should be faster than your approach (I do not know how it is implemented either) is that `Join` knows about both collections, so it can sort both (by `HashCodes`) and then iterate simultaneously by both collections which will result in something like `O(n)` on iteration phase (though this algorithm will add second sorting while yours have only one).

Comment: @Snowbear: Full of curiosity I've looked at Join implementation through ILSpy. Suprisingly it seems very similar to my code :D. i.e. a lookup on inner list (users) then iteration over outer list (orders)

Comment: @dig, They've stolen your solution!! Ok, I'll try to implement it in my way and check how will it behave then get back. Now I'm full of curiosity too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SelectMany or join depending on weather you are using linq-to-sql or linq with local collections. If you are using local collections the better way is to use join, else use SelectMany.

Like this...join:

```
var selection = (from s in SupplierList
                 join o in s.childholders on s.userid equals o.userid
                 select new { username = o.username);
```

or, in case of linq-to-sql:

```
var selection = (from s in SupplierList
                 from o in s.childholders 
                 select { username = o.username);
```

You can then use the anonymous type you projected the way you want.

Comment: minor point...i think you need to say 'equals' in your join, not '=='.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jon, but you *could* say:

```
var orders = (from s in supplier
              from o in s.childorders
              select new
              { 
                  Order = o, 
                  User = _users.First(p => p.userid == o.userid) 
              }).ToList();

foreach(var order in orders) {
    order.Order.username = order.User.username;
}
```

Untested of course :)

Comment: You're setting `username` of anonymous type in the last line. You haven't tested it, but our mind-compilation skills are strong!

Comment: Oh yeah, gah I've just realised what I've done. The other answers are better than mine anyway. UPDATE: fixed?

Answer (score 1):

First a question...

It looks like you are operating on every order.  Why do you need to cycle through the supplierlist first since you don't seem to be using it inside the loop?  Unless there are orders that don't belong to any supplierlist, you might be able to skip that step.

If that isn't the case, then I think you can use a join.  If you aren't familiar with the syntax for joins in linq, this is one (simplified) way to approach it:

```
var x = from S in SupplierList
        join C in childorders on C.supplierlistID equals S.ID
        where [whatever you need here if anything]
        select new { field1, field2};
foreach var y in x 
{

}
```

Note I assumed a foreign key in childorders to supplierlist.  If that isn't the case you will have to modify accordingly.

Hope that helps.